# Ignore Rounding Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there any possible way for Power BI to ignore rounding? I just want to use the whole number and sip the rounding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

INT ( [your number] )

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Ignore-Rounding/m-p/799623#M384794

Create another column or measure.

Answer (score 0):

In your measure expression text box, you could use a TRUNC() function to exclude all decimals. Below is a nice guide.

```
https://dax.guide/trunc/
```